# Dimensional model aggregations for nested/fractional objects

Tags: data-modeling, data-warehouse

Suppose I've created a game where users can submit requests to buy and sell goods through an online marketplace.  Each sell request can contain "sub-requests" for multiple goods types.  Each buy request can only fulfill one of the sub-requests, and the parent sell request is then no longer active/available. (Call the market dynamics messed-up if you would like, but please bear with me...)

I'd like to aggregate this data to start understanding and analyzing the trends.  For argument's sake, let's presume there's enough action within the marketplace that I can't effectively store and/or query the raw, transaction-level data so I have to use aggregates.

Each sell request generates a log entry approximately like this:

```
{
    sellRequestID: 123,
    userID: 456,
    timestamp: 1449043403,
    country: "United States",
    goods: [ "eggs", "beef", "chicken" ]
}
```

A buy request might generate a log entry approximately like this:

```
{
    buyRequestID: 987,
    sellRequestID: 123,
    userID: 789,
    timestamp: 1449043408,
    good: "eggs"
}
```

I would like to be able to answer questions like:

1. What is the total number of sell requests submitted by day and country?
2. What is the total number of individual goods sell requests (child requests) submitted by day and country? (To an extent, this reveals the "request inflation factor", or average number of goods per sell request).
3. What is the total number of child requests submitted by day, country, and type (i.e. what's the total "availability" of each good in the seller market)?

Assuming I have relatively standard dimension tables:

```
users            countries        goods
-----            ---------        -----
456 John Smith   1 United States  1 eggs
789 Jane Doe     2 Canada         2 beef
... ...          . ...            3 chicken
```

A table that could answer my first question might look like:

```
Date        CountryID        Total Requests
2015-12-01  1                1,000,000
2015-12-01  2                200,000
...
```

A table that could answer my second question and third questions might look like:

```
Date        CountryID  GoodID      Total Requests
2015-12-01  1          1           600,000
2015-12-01  1          2           300,000
2015-12-01  1          3           400,000
...
```

Is there a design that would allow me to answer all questions in a single table? I've considered a couple possibilities, and am looking for any practical experience or advice.

If I use the second schema above, I would end up inflating the number of parent requests when trying to answer question 1, and would lose the ability to "deduplicate" those parent request counts.

One approach might be to use a schema like:

```
Date       CountryID  GoodID    Parent Requests    Child Requests
```

If I do that, to avoid the inflation in the prior scenario, I would need to "fractionalize" the parent requests - e.g. a request containing three goods would still add 1 to the child requests column across three rows, but would add 1/3 to the parent requests aggregates.  Similarly a request with two goods would add 1/2 to the parent requests column across its two rows.  So I might have data like:

```
Date       CountryID  GoodID    Parent Requests    Child Requests
2015-12-01 1          1         1/3                1
2015-12-01 1          2         5/6                2
2015-12-01 1          3         5/6                2
```

Now my aggregations for the parent requests (ignoring the goodID) column will sum to the expected 2 requests, but I still retain the ability to understand that in 2 parent requests, I had the opportunity to buy eggs once, beef twice, and chicken twice.

Are there any downsides to this fractional approach? Am I trying to shoehorn something that shouldn't be shoe-horned? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Not a straight answer, per se, but a few thoughts.

1) The downside to your approach is that the fraction in Parent Requests will be semi-additive, so you'll need to carefully controls any queries that aggregate that column.  This may seem trivial, but it can kick your butt as you add dimensions or maybe your end-user community grows.  If you go this route, you may want to replace the names "Parent Requests" and "Child Requests" with something more business-focused.  You can discuss that with your users.  Off the cuff, I might try replacing "Child Requests" with just "Requests" since it applies directly to the natural key, and maybe replace "Parent Requests" with something like "Good_to_Request_Ratio."  (I already dislike that.)

2) Properly indexed, a weighted bridge table could provide the solution.  But it's many more rows.  In that case, you add a "Request" dimension that is bridged to the Good dimension.

3) I don't understand the requirement to answer all questions with one fact table.  The table design must first and foremost meet the functional and non-functional analytic requirements.  One table at the Country/Date grain and another at the Country/Date/Good is fine, especially when the "requests" measure at the finer grain is semi-additive and won't sum to the coarser grain.